# How to perform asynchronous procedures on a background thread during application startup without blocking?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, xaml, asynchronous

Simply put, I can not see what is blocking the UI, nor how to fix it. I've been staring at this for hours.

From the beginning,

App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="Front_Office.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
             >

    <Application.Resources>
      ......   
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

App.xaml.cs

```
using Front_Office.ViewModels;
using System.Windows;

namespace Front_Office
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        protected async override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);
            var mainWindow = new MainWindow { DataContext = await MainWindowViewModel.Create() };
            mainWindow.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System.Windows;

namespace Front_Office
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Factory pattern used to create MainWindowViewModel with asynchronous calls.

```
public static async Task<MainWindowViewModel> Create()
{
    var myClass = new MainWindowViewModel();
    await myClass.Initialize();
    return myClass;
}

private async Task Initialize()
{
    PatientList = await GetPatientList();
    FilteredPatientList = PatientList;
}

private MainWindowViewModel() : base()
{
}
```

GetPatientList()

```
    private Task<ObservableCollection<ViewPatient>> GetPatientList()
        {
            IsLoading = true;

            var x = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(30000);  // SIMULATING A VERY LONG CALL.
                return new ObservableCollection<ViewPatient>(await MedicalClient.GetAllPatientsAsync());
            });

            IsLoading = false;
            return x;
        }
```

I am trying to run `MedicalClient.GetAllPatientsAsync()` and `Thread.Sleep()` on a background thread so as not to block the UI on application startup. No luck.

What am I doing wrong?

Any help is most welcome.

Edit #1:

By making the following changes, it seems to work as I need. Is this the correct way to do this? (It seems to break the factory pattern as described here on SO).

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for App.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class App : Application
{
    // Droped the async and the await
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
         base.OnStartup(e);
         var mainWindow = new MainWindow { DataContext = MainWindowViewModel.Create() };
         mainWindow.Show();
    }
}

// Dropped async and await. Added Task.Run()
public static MainWindowViewModel Create()
{
      var myClass = new MainWindowViewModel();  // Create/Load ViewModel
      Task.Run(()=> myClass.Initialize());      // Update ViewModel from Asynchronous methods.
      return myClass;
}
```

Comment: What is happening?  Is that code running at startup but blocking the UI?  Or is your Task not running at startup at all?  Think I have an idea..

Comment: @FernandoRodriguez Task is running, but UI is blocked while Task.Run(...) is executing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work mostly in ASP land--I'm spinning up a WPF project real quick.  I'm thinking the problem is that you are using the MainView's "Initialize" method which is actually being called synchronously.

Or if my jargon is wrong, at the very least Initialize() has to complete before the view will render.  I was about to recommend using like the OnStartup class, where I saw you had the following line:

`var mainWindow = new MainWindow { DataContext = await MainWindowViewModel.Create() };`

Problem being is then upon application startup your code calls `Create()` which itself awaits `Intitialize()` so I'm assuming that is where the app is locking up on startup unless I'm mistaken.  Can you throw in a few break points and confirm?

My suggestion would be like below--but it would still require refactoring since it appears your object depends upon the data actually being loaded to display.

```
    protected async override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        var mainData = await GetPatientList();
        // Your MainWindowViewModel's Create() call would have to 
        //undo it's dependency on GetPatientList(), however.  I don't really
        //have a coherent example
        var mainWindow = new MainWindow { DataContext = await MainWindowViewModel.Create() };
        mainWindow.Show();
    }
```

Comment: Sorry...I have no idea how to move GetPatientList() out of MainWindowViewModel to accomplish this. Also, in the full code, GetPatientList() is of but one of serveral different async procedures. (The code was reduced to the minimum for SO example). Thanks.

Comment: Please see my above Edit.

Comment: @AlanWayne I didn't promise 100% best practices!  I just noticed logic was a little jumbled. Even though we "have" the async and await keywords, I've still used the Task.Run() method when I need something to spin off and run separately from an existing spot in code.  I was hoping someone would edit my answer to be more "best practice".  Glad you got it working for now tho :)

Comment: +1 Your idea here is essentially what I ended up doing in my edit and is in keeping with Stephen Cleary's comment.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In your case UI thread not blocked, it is just have nothing to show.
Here is your problem:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected async override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        var mainWindow = new MainWindow
            { DataContext = await MainWindowViewModel.Create() };

        //next line will be executed after "Create" method will complete

        mainWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

`await` keyword will stop executing current method, freed current thread(continue executing caller method or continue with next event...) and continue only when task is completed.
Because `mainWindow` not initialized yet, application have nothing to show.

I think you can move initialization of `MainWindow.DataContext` inside MainWindow (for example `Load` eventhandler), then window will be showed immediately and filled with data when `Create` method is complete

Comment: I'm confused. As I understand the factory pattern for class creation with asynchronous calls in the constructor, the constructor for MainWindowViewModel is private--and can't be reached from MainWindow.xaml.cs.  Is this correct?

Comment: Please see my above Edit.

Comment: @AlanWayne: You can't use an async factory pattern for view models. You'll have to create it in some kind of a "loading" state, and then *update* the VM properties once initialization completes.

Comment: @StephenCleary Could you please give an example?? How do I trigger an update after it has loaded? Thanks.

Comment: @AlanWayne: In MVVM, updates are done with `INotifyPropertyChanged`. I have a complete example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx).